# Find a pointer T* in std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr> (C++20)

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, c++20, unordered-set

As pointed out in [Using a std::unordered_set of std::unique_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851088/using-a-stdunordered-set-of-stdunique-ptr), it is not easy to find a pointer `T*` in `std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<T>>`. Prior to C++20 we were forced to construct an instance of `std::unique_ptr<T>`.

Thanks to the *Heterogeneous lookup for unordered containers* proposals (http://wg21.link/P0919r3 and http://wg21.link/p1690r1), this problem is solved in C++20. But the available solution looks quite clumsy to me (even by C++ standards). It seems like I need to implement from scratch not one, but two functors (for transparent hashing and for transparent comparison):

```cc
template<class T>
struct Equal {
    using is_transparent = void;
    bool operator()(const std::unique_ptr<T>& lhs, const std::unique_ptr<T>& rhs) const {
        return lhs == rhs;
    }
    bool operator()(const std::unique_ptr<T>& lhs, const T* rhs) const {
        return lhs.get() == rhs;
    }
    bool operator()(const T* lhs, const std::unique_ptr<T>& rhs) const {
        return lhs == rhs.get();
    }
};

template<class T>
struct Hash {
    using is_transparent = void;
    size_t operator()(const std::unique_ptr<T>& ptr) const {
        return std::hash<const T*>()(ptr.get());
    }
    size_t operator()(const T* ptr) const {
        return std::hash<const T*>()(ptr);
    }
};

template<class T>
using UnorderedSetOfUniquePtrs = std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<T>, Hash<T>, Equal<T>>;
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bqx714 (the proposal is currently implemented only in MSVC).

This works but looks like A LOT of boilerplate. Am I missing something? Is there a way to use IDK maybe some standard transparent hasher or equality comparator? I see that `std::equal_to<void>` is transparent, but I cannot use it directly. Maybe there is a sneaky way to define `unique_ptr<T> -> T*` implicit conversion "just for this `UnorderedSetOfUniquePtrs` class"? Your ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shift the verbosity into [std::to_address](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/to_address) (thanks to @Caleth for pointing that out) and the existing `std::hash`, which is specialized for `std::unique_ptr` to return a hash based on the raw address (thanks to @Mikhail for the hint). Then, implement hash and equality types with member function templates (note how you no longer need the types themselves be templates):

```
struct Equal {
    using is_transparent = void;
    template<class U, class S>
    bool operator()(const U& lhs, const S& rhs) const { 
        return std::to_address(lhs) == std::to_address(rhs); 
    }
};

struct Hash {
    using is_transparent = void;
    template<class U>
    size_t operator()(const U& ptr) const {
        return std::hash<U>{}();
    }
}
```

Comment: missing argument `ptr` for the `hash` call